# Using JavaScript and jQuery to validate required fields. When validation fails, returning screen back to normal conditions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using JavaScript and `jquery.validate.min.js` to validate fields. During this process a "WORKING" gif is displayed and the "SAVE/EDIT" buttons is hidden. Should the validation fail, screen returns but the save and edit buttons are still hidden and the working gif is displayed.  How do I get the GIF to hide again and the save/edit buttons displayed?

```
function processing() {
    // if the validation process (required fields not provided) then the add/save buttons is invisible and the GIF is still running active.
    // Will need to figure out how to get the required to also hide the working gif and reshow the save/cancel button
    //$('.saveeditbuttons').hide();
    var thisdiv = '.processingmsg';
    $(thisdiv).css({ "position": "absolute", "top": "170px", left: ($(window).width() - $(thisdiv).outerWidth())/2, });
    Move = $(thisdiv).detach()
    $('body').append(Move);         
    $(thisdiv).show();
    $("form").submit();
}
```

Comment: In your HTML, put the gif img tag inside a div element with an id, such as <div id='loader-animation">  ... my gif ... </div>. Then to hide, do this in javascript: $("#loader-animation").hide();

Comment: Thanks.  The gif is inside a div and the save/edit buttons are also inside a div.